# Can a Telegram user answer on behalf of a Telegram Bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I would like to know if a Telegram user can answer on behalf of a Telegram Bot?

For example in the banks, when you start chatting, the bot responds to you until you ask for customer service and there a customer representative takes control and starts chatting with you directly.

I know you can use the api to answer via your project web app, but I would like to know if there is a way so that you can redirect the bot queries to a person when this is asked and that person can answer vía Telegram app.

If not, is there any other solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the bot is just some code you wrote, of course you can add functionality to forward messages from/to a different user that is also chatting with the bot.

Comment: Great! That is just what I need, do you know how the method is called to forward those kind of messages?

Comment: Programming :D Again, it's up to you what to do with the messages received from a user. Nothing stops you from taking it and sending it to a different user.